# GtkExpander collapses unintendedly

Tags: c, gtk, gtk3

In the following example, compiled with GTK3, GtkExpander collapses unintendedly when I click in the entry field.

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

static void destroy (GtkWidget *widget, gpointer data)
{
    gtk_main_quit ();
}

int main( int   argc,
          char *argv[] )
{
    gtk_init (&argc, &argv);

    GtkWidget *entry;
    entry = gtk_entry_new ();

    GtkWidget *expander;
    expander = gtk_expander_new ("test");
    gtk_expander_set_expanded (GTK_EXPANDER(expander), TRUE);
    gtk_container_add (GTK_CONTAINER(expander), entry);

    GtkWidget *window;
    window = gtk_window_new (GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
    gtk_container_add (GTK_CONTAINER(window), expander);
    g_signal_connect (window, "destroy", G_CALLBACK (destroy), NULL);
    gtk_widget_show_all (window);

    gtk_main ();
    return 0;
}
```

However, GtkExpander does *not* collapse if it is expanded after `gtk_widget_show_all()`, i.e.:

```
    gtk_widget_show_all (window);
    gtk_expander_set_expanded (GTK_EXPANDER(expander), TRUE);
```

What's wrong with expanding the widget before `gtk_widget_show_all()`?

Comment: It works on Gtk 3.22 (Fedora 25). Which version are you using?

Comment: It's 3.22.11 here.

Comment: Maybe I'm not getting your question. Here, ther expander starts expanded and can be collapsed using `gtk_expander_set_expanded` before or after `gtk_widget_show_all`

Comment: Yes, it starts expanded, that's ok. But the first mouse click onto the entry widget (not the expander!) collapses the expander.

Comment: Just tested and it's ok, stays expanded, cursor starts blinking and entry has focus. I've just copy-pasted your code.

Comment: compiled with `gcc expander.c -o expander \`pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-3.0\``

Comment: That's weird. It doesn't work here... Btw, only the very first click into the entry box triggers the closing of the expander. After the first click, expander and entry box work as usual.

Comment: Well, can't see how to reproduce the problem. here the behavior is exactly the same, before or after `gtk_widget_show_all`. :/

Comment: Ok, let's see if someone else can reproduce this. Thanks for testing.

Comment: I am getting the same problem using Gtk 3.22.15-1

Comment: Works as expected (expander stays open). Gtk 3.18.9, compiled with the @JoséFonte method. How are you compiling?

Comment: @theGtknerd Same command as José.

Comment: Maybe we should compare distros. I use Linux Mint (Ubuntu 16.04 derivative).

Comment: Ubuntu 17.04 here.

Comment: Fedora 25 here but Ubuntu 17 should have the latest Gtk, maybe some bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a bug in GTK+ which is fixed now.

For details see:

- https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=783145
- https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=774134